# how to convert Nuxt js (pwa) project to apk?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, apk

I am working on a nuxt project and I want to add it to Google Play, but it requires an apk output
so is there any solution to get the apk file from Nuxt?

I've already tried using android studio but it was unsuccessful
manifest.json:

```json
{
  "name": "my nuxt app",
  "short_name": "my lovely nuxt app",
  "description": "pwa to apk",
  "icons": [
    {
      "src": "/logo.png",
      "sizes": "192x192",
      "type": "image/png"
    },
    {
      "src": "/300.png",
      "sizes": "384x384",
      "type": "image/jpg"
    },{
      "src": "/512.jpg",
      "sizes": "512x512",
      "type": "image/jpg"
    }
  ],
  "start_url": "/?standalone=true",
  "display": "standalone",
  "background_color": "#222",
  "theme_color": "#222",
  "lang": "fa",
  "prefer_related_applications": true
}
```

and I get this error when I want to install it:

**for security your phone is set to block installation**

Comment: Well not really, you should use somthing like https://capacitorjs.com/

Comment: yes i guess i found the solution and if everything goes well ;I will share the answer with you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after so many searches and thanks to @kissu  for give me a hint about twa i found the solution:

1.first of all u need a service worker for your nuxt project and put it in the **static** folder

example:

/static/sw.js
and inside of sw.js:

```
 const options = {"workboxURL":"https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/workbox-cdn@5.1.4/workbox/workbox-sw.js","importScripts":[],"config":{"debug":false},"cacheOptions":{"cacheId":"online-actor-prod","directoryIndex":"/","revision":"c35hcbL1ctml"},"clientsClaim":true,"skipWaiting":true,"cleanupOutdatedCaches":true,"offlineAnalytics":false,"preCaching":[{"revision":"c35hcbL1ctml","url":"/"}],"runtimeCaching":[{"urlPattern":"/_nuxt/","handler":"CacheFirst","method":"GET","strategyPlugins":[]},{"urlPattern":"/","handler":"NetworkFirst","method":"GET","strategyPlugins":[]}],"offlinePage":null,"pagesURLPattern":"/","offlineStrategy":"NetworkFirst"}

importScripts(...[options.workboxURL, ...options.importScripts])

initWorkbox(workbox, options)
workboxExtensions(workbox, options)
precacheAssets(workbox, options)
cachingExtensions(workbox, options)
runtimeCaching(workbox, options)
offlinePage(workbox, options)
routingExtensions(workbox, options)

function getProp(obj, prop) {
  return prop.split('.').reduce((p, c) => p[c], obj)
}

function initWorkbox(workbox, options) {
  if (options.config) {
    // Set workbox config
    workbox.setConfig(options.config)
  }

  if (options.cacheNames) {
    // Set workbox cache names
    workbox.core.setCacheNameDetails(options.cacheNames)
  }

  if (options.clientsClaim) {
    // Start controlling any existing clients as soon as it activates
    workbox.core.clientsClaim()
  }

  if (options.skipWaiting) {
    workbox.core.skipWaiting()
  }

  if (options.cleanupOutdatedCaches) {
    workbox.precaching.cleanupOutdatedCaches()
  }

  if (options.offlineAnalytics) {
    // Enable offline Google Analytics tracking
    workbox.googleAnalytics.initialize()
  }
}

function precacheAssets(workbox, options) {
  if (options.preCaching.length) {
    workbox.precaching.precacheAndRoute(options.preCaching, options.cacheOptions)
  }
}


function runtimeCaching(workbox, options) {
  const requestInterceptor = {
    requestWillFetch({ request }) {
      if (request.cache === 'only-if-cached' && request.mode === 'no-cors') {
        return new Request(request.url, { ...request, cache: 'default', mode: 'no-cors' })
      }
      return request
    },
    fetchDidFail(ctx) {
      ctx.error.message =
        '[workbox] Network request for ' + ctx.request.url + ' threw an error: ' + ctx.error.message
      console.error(ctx.error, 'Details:', ctx)
    },
    handlerDidError(ctx) {
      ctx.error.message =
        `[workbox] Network handler threw an error: ` + ctx.error.message
      console.error(ctx.error, 'Details:', ctx)
      return null
    }
  }

  for (const entry of options.runtimeCaching) {
    const urlPattern = new RegExp(entry.urlPattern)
    const method = entry.method || 'GET'

    const plugins = (entry.strategyPlugins || [])
      .map(p => new (getProp(workbox, p.use))(...p.config))

    plugins.unshift(requestInterceptor)

    const strategyOptions = { ...entry.strategyOptions, plugins }

    const strategy = new workbox.strategies[entry.handler](strategyOptions)

    workbox.routing.registerRoute(urlPattern, strategy, method)
  }
}

function offlinePage(workbox, options) {
  if (options.offlinePage) {
    // Register router handler for offlinePage
    workbox.routing.registerRoute(new RegExp(options.pagesURLPattern), ({ request, event }) => {
      const strategy = new workbox.strategies[options.offlineStrategy]
      return strategy
        .handle({ request, event })
        .catch(() => caches.match(options.offlinePage))
    })
  }
}

function workboxExtensions(workbox, options) {
  
}

function cachingExtensions(workbox, options) {
  
}

function routingExtensions(workbox, options) {
  
}
```

2.you also need a manifest , for that put this code in your nuxt.config.js:

```
export default{
 pwa: {
    manifest: {
      name: 'example name',
      short_name: 'example',
      lang: 'fa',
      theme_color: '#222',
      background_color: '#222',
      start_url: `/`,
      prefer_related_applications: true,
    },
    icon: {
      fileName: 'logo.png'
    },

   },
  }
```

3.now everything is ready to create your apk, now you can search for pwa to apk in google And use sites that offer these services:
ive already tried these sites and all working well:

[gonative.io](https://gonative.io/)
or
[pwabuilder.com](https://pwabuilder.com)

Answer (score 1):

TWA are a thing as you can read here: https://www.ateamsoftsolutions.com/what-are-pwa-and-twa/

Meanwhile, this is not the same as having an `.apk` which is something totally different from the Web platform as you can see here: https://fileinfo.com/extension/apk (none of the extensions are ones used on the Web)

This is a totally different bundle language and ecosystem. Hence, you cannot port a PWA into a Google Play app.

You'll need to learn ways to make a mobile app with either Capacitor (Quasar) can help or similar solutions.

Or use React Native, Flutter or even vanilla Kotlin (the latter being the closest one to the machine).

Answer (score 0):

In addition to kissu's comment, I always use Nuxt.js for regular websites but [Ionic/Vue](https://ionicframework.com/docs/vue/overview) with [Capacitor](https://capacitorjs.com) for mobile apps, it works great, same ecosystem and a great UI components and CLI from Ionic. This is just a suggestion for something that works and it has a minimum learning curve.