# Is it possible to put nuxt.js (pwa or spa) in the appstore?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, app-store

The truth is, since nuxt works poorly in some native access, such as accessing the file manager or sending notifications to iPhone users, I am not sure if appstore supports nuxt projects or not. That's why before I start the new project, I had a question whether it is possible to put a nuxt project in appstore or not? (If the answer is yes, please guide how to do it)
Or using something like react or react native is a better option ?

Any answer from you would be greatly appreciated

Comment: @kissu I tried to convince the client of this project that there is no need to put your project in the APPSTORE, and he replied: "Maybe you are right, but accept that people will trust store applications more than websites."
In fact, this is the request of all customers, let's be honest, pwa is not good as a site (as you know, SEO and security are very time-consuming) nor as an application (lack of native access).

Comment: @kissu The minimum requirement of a client is to be able to send notifications to its users!! And I think they are right.
For these reasons, I have decided not to use nuxt or vue anymore and run my projects with react and react.native, it is true that the development speed is lower in these, but at least I will not be ashamed in front of my clients and my conscience.

Answer (score 1):

As per Apple’s App Store policy-

> “Your app should include features, content, and UI that elevate it beyond a repackaged website. If your app is not particularly useful, unique, or “app-like,” it does not belong on the App Store.”

So no, you can’t throw a PWA in the App Store.

Google is far more accommodating in this respect, and welcomes PWAs in the Google Play Store. They also have their own publishing guidelines, so you’d want to read up on them.

React Native is an option for both the App Store and Play Store, so I’d recommend that if you’re comfortable with it.

Comment: What if the application I want to design does not need native access? In this case, is it possible to register it in the app store? @nick-dawes

Comment: @ArianFm if it doesn't need it, why even building a mobile app in the first place?

Comment: @kissu For example, digital currency exchanges do not need native access,  interface will be better if instead of opening the browser and then entering the url , access it by just clicking on the application!

Comment: @ArianFm not sure to fully understand but a PWA can also do that (being a icon in your phone). Also, it seems quite a small issue if it's the main thing about having a mobile app.

Comment: Arian it doesn't matter if your web app requires access to native hardware or code libraries- it's still a web app, and you can't publish web apps to the app store. As kissu mentioned, on an iOS device you can simply tap "Add to Home Screen" to have your PWA accessible by just clicking an icon. But as it's still a web app, it'll open in a web browser.

Comment: Not like it changes a lot anyway, just a skeleton for some HTTP calls nothing more either it be a website or a mobile app.

Comment: I understand what you both mean, but the problem is that for example COINEX, which is a digital currency exchange, is built with NUXT.js and was in the appstore until a few months ago, the question is if I change the PWA to something else like TWA( as @kissu mentioned) Will it be possible to register in the app store or not?
ps:The reason why nuxt was used for this exchange is that socket.io is relatively easy for this framework compared to its competitors
In fact, the reason why I try so hard to use nuxt instead of react.native is exactly the same socket.io issue

Comment: @ArianFm why is it no in the appstore? This may be a reason of it not being suitable (maybe forced to be removed). At the end of the day, you're looking for a mobile app for the wrong reasons. The implementation of websockets is probably not that hard to do elsewhere (moreover it looks like the `socket-io` module is not yet compatible with Nuxt3 anyway). If you want a mobile app or something on the store, you should have specific needs. Don't start trying to hack things that should be simply done. Create a website with some websockets and ship it with your favorite stack.

Comment: @kissu The reason why it was removed was the in-app payment, which is not possible according to the rules of the appstore, exactly The same thing happened to  Fortnite ! :D .
And in the end, you are quite logical, but it is strange that I have seen many apps in the app store with react and vue , which are suitable for pwa, but they exist there anyway, in fact, I feel sorry for nuxt(as u mentioned:meta-framework of Vue), which with so many capabilities,seems it is not available in the appstore.
Or maybe there is, we don't know!

Comment: @ArianFm yeah, I followed a bit the Fortnite drama. How do you know that the apps seens on the store are based on Vue? React is logical because you have React Native but Vue doesn't have any specific capabilities for a mobile app. Any proof that some of them are done in Vue/Nuxt? And again, there is no need to ship it to an appstore if it's just for the principle of being on a store. It's expensive, takes time to get reviewed, have quite some limitations and is more complex. A website is far easier on a comparison.

Comment: @kissu I was considering the names of some of them, but since I live in Iran and the government has restricted the internet due to the protests and has taken access to the App Store and Google Play from its people to prevent the use of vpn SMH, I cannot enter and tell you their exact names. But some of them were offered in the previous companies I worked for, such as six2fit (this project was removed from the list of Google Play and Appstore due to US sanctions), Divar or snapp are another part of these applications, all of which are designed with Vue. but were removed due to sanctions

Comment: Hm not friendly for sure. Still, we're missing the critical part here: how they were configured/bundled to then be pushed towards a store. Also, having just a Chrome wrapper around (like Cordova) is far from being the best thing from a performance standing point so I'd rather use a website sometimes (faster, more flexible, less configuration issues for the million of mobile devices, cheaper etc etc...).

Comment: @kissu All that was needed was to create a raw android or swift project and put something like an iframe from the vue project inside it, so it was basically a swift project with vue inside it.

Comment: @ArianFm yeah no, please don't do that. Probably one of the worst approaches. Make a quick, simple and efficient website and forget about putting it on the store: no benefit at all here.

Comment: @kissu yep I guess u right , Maybe one day we will hear about nuxt native and we will all cheer ✌

Comment: @ArianFm the current focus of Nuxt3 right now is more the ability of being used on any kind of envrionment like Edge rendering, service workers etc. The mobile realm is not the web platform and is something totally different. As I told in my answer, you can always use Ionic if you really want something done for there. But no, nothing will be native for mobile because it's not what Nuxt is meant for. And you don't really need a mobile app anyway for your purpose.

Answer (score 1):

First off, Nuxt is a meta-framework of Vue.
Meaning that it is a superset of Vue, bringing SSR/SSG capabilities + DX features.

It's clearly not a "mobile app-frienly starter" because it's still aimed towards Web.

You could use some modules to bring mobile capabilities like this one: https://ionic.roe.dev/
Here is a video on how to use Ionic + Vue + Vite overall: https://youtu.be/-FwQ6c6OreQ

As for the PWA approach, you can use a [TWA app](https://medium.com/@kevinkurniawan97/introduction-to-pwa-twa-dcc2368268a3) for sure but it's quite a stretch as you can guess.

You've already asked a similar [question here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72368206/8816585) btw, not a lot changed since then.

Overall, if you have bigger mobile needs you can always look into webview tools (Ionic, Cordova etc), React Native, Flutter or directly into Kotlin/Swift. All of them having their own pro/cons.

Comment: So why should you use nuxt or pwa in general? Isn't the purpose of using pwa to have an application and a site at the same time?

Comment: A website (notice web) that is responsive can be a good idea for a lot of things, especially if properly responsive. Adding PWA will make it even better but still focused for a web experience: desktop, tablet + mobile. A mobile app goes further in terms of local data access, performance, gyroscopy, framerate, battery etc but is not as polyvalent and requires more work to work efficiently. This kind of question can be answered by looking in your favorite search engine for further details. The border between mobile and web is thin, the decision comes down to your actual needs in that field @Ari